# How to calculate similarity between two voices in android?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am developing android educational app which users can study English.
In this app, I am going to put the function to calculate similarity between teacher's voice and user's voice.

By using this app, user can listen to teacher's voice and after user can speak listened sentence.
Then app will show user the similarity percent like as 90%.

I have tried many google searches but i did not find the exact one.

If you have experiences in speech comparing then please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Analysing the two voices won't give you a measure of how well the student is learning the language. What you could do is use speech-to-text to transcribe each sentence, and then compare how similar the text is.

Comment: Hi, @billynomates. I have already implemented that way by using pocketsphinx. I want my app to work offline also so i have selected pocketsphinx for this. But the accurary is very bad. And for english learning, i think accent and tone is very important so i am going to compare speeches.